# press a button it takes me to Apple Settings app

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

How can I do when I press a button it takes me to Apple Settings app

Like this ...
But it puts me in my app settings

I want to go the usual settings app

USE Swift

```
    @IBAction func settingsApp() {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8.0) {

} else {
    //iOS 8 specific code here
    [self openSettings];
}


- (void)openSettings
{
    BOOL canOpenSettings = (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL);
    if (canOpenSettings) {


        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

Comment: I just put a button on the VIEW I want him to send me the settings of the device

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func settingsApp(sender: UIButton) {
    let appSettings = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
    if let gotoUrl = appSettings {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(gotoUrl)
    }
}
```